# Crash after playing 10-15 levels

Tags: ios, runtime-error, ccparticlesystem

I am using CCParticleSystemQuad to simulate exploding effect. After playing 10-15 levels on device, it crashes and i'm getting an error message

`Assertion failure in -[CCParticleSystemQuad initWithFile:]`

and pointing to CCParticleSystem.m class `NSAssert( dict != nil, @"Particles: file not found");`

Here is my code :

```
for(NSString *star in starsArray)
{
    explosion1 = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:star];
    explosion1.position = sprite.position;
    explosion1.autoRemoveOnFinish=YES;
    explosion1.blendAdditive=GL_ZERO;
    [self addChild:explosion1 z:11];
    [explosion1 resetSystem];

}
```